# How to get summary of different models inside loop?

Tags: r, loops

I have 30 different non linear models named as model1, model2, ...., model30. I want to summarize them inside loop in R . I have tried this code but returns no value.

```
n = 0
while (n<15){
  model = paste("model",n, sep = "")
  summary(model)
  n = n + 1}
```

How can I solve this issue without typing summary after each model?

Comment: Try `summary(get(model))`. But you will have to assign the value to a variable or to print it with an actual `print` statement, inside a loop autoprinting doesn't work.

Comment: Or `lapply(mget(paste("model", 0:14, sep = "_")), summary)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @rui-barradas comments and assuming that you just want to print the results to the console.

```r
n = 1
while (n < 31) {
   model <- paste("model", n, sep = "")
   print(summary(get(model)))
   n = n + 1
}
```

Or if you want to print to screen plus have the ability to cleanly create an object with all the results...

```r
results1to30 <- lapply(mget(paste("model", 1:30, sep = "")), summary)
```